# docker copy file from one container to another?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is what I want to do:

1. docker-compose build
2. docker-compose $COMPOSE_ARGS run --rm task1
3. docker-compose $COMPOSE_ARGS run --rm task2
4. docker-compose $COMPOSE_ARGS run --rm combine-both-task2
5. docker-compose $COMPOSE_ARGS run --rm selenium-test

And a docker-compose.yml that looks like this:

```
task1:
  build: ./task1
  volumes_from:
    - task1_output
  command: ./task1.sh

task1_output:
  image: alpine:3.3
  volumes:
    - /root/app/dist
  command: /bin/sh

# essentially I want to copy task1 output into task2 because they each use different images and use different tech stacks... 
task2:
  build: ../task2
  volumes_from:
    - task2_output
    - task1_output:ro
  command: /bin/bash -cx "mkdir -p task1 && cp -R /root/app/dist/* ."
```

So now all the required files are in task2 container... how would I start up a web server and expose a port with the content in task2?

I am stuck here... how do I access the stuff from task2_output in my combine-tasks/Dockerfile:

```
combine-both-task2:
  build: ../combine-tasks
  volumes_from:
     - task2_output
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In recent versions of docker, [named volumes replace data containers](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17798) as the easy way to share data between containers.

```
docker volume create --name myshare
docker run -v myshare:/shared task1
docker run -v myshare:/shared -p 8080:8080 task2
...
```

Those commands will set up one local volume, and the `-v myshare:/shared` argument will make that share available as the folder `/shared` inside each of each container.

To express that in a compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  task1:
    build: ./task1
  volumes:
    - 'myshare:/shared'

  task2:
    build: ./task2
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  volumes:
    - 'myshare:/shared'

volumes:
  myshare:
    driver: local
```

To test this out, I made a small project:

```
- docker-compose.yml (above)
- task1/Dockerfile
- task1/app.py
- task2/Dockerfile
```

I used node's http-server as `task2/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /shared
CMD http-server
```

and `task1/Dockerfile` used `python:alpine`, to show two different stacks writing and reading.

```
FROM python:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
CMD python app.py
```

here's `task1/app.py`

```
import time

count = 0
while True:
  fname = '/shared/{}.txt'.format(count)
  with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    f.write('content {}'.format(count))
    count = count + 1
  time.sleep(10)
```

Take those four files, and run them via `docker compose up` in the directory with `docker-compose.yml` - then visit $DOCKER_HOST:8080 to see a steadily updated list of files.

Also, I'm using docker version `1.12.0` and compose version `1.8.0` but this should work for a few versions back.

And be sure to check out the docker docs for details I've probably missed here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Comment: I tried your example by having task1 creating hello.txt and then try to find that file in task2 and the following is output:
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> f8d79ba03c00
Step 2 : RUN echo "hello" > hello.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3f2e4e8df3ec
Successfully built 3f2e4e8df3ec
Building task2
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> f8d79ba03c00
Step 2 : WORKDIR /shared
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bc2f077838ce
Step 3 : RUN ls hello.txt
 ---> Running in 6b6e1eb63f7f
ls: cannot access 'hello.txt': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'task2' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ls hello.txt'

Comment: The confusion might be around build time, vs run time.  The volume share only exists during `docker run`, not `docker build`.  So `RUN ls hello.txt` isn't connected to the share to read, and `RUN echo "hello" > hello.txt` only writes locally to the first image.  I'll add the full python dockerfile so you can copy all for pieces of my example.

Comment: Thank you Jett. I think you are absolutely right, it's build time vs run time. Essentially I want task1 to produce some artefacts such as npm run dist (to produce js, images etc files), and then task2 copy these files into its image and then start up tomcat. And task3 then runs selenium against task2.  Thank you for your help so far

Comment: Glad that helped.  It sounds like the next step is to make a script that does any reading or writing to a volume, and make those scripts the `CMD` instruction for the container. `app.py` and `http-server` are using the volume this way in my example.

Answer (score 4):

For me the best way to copy file from or to container is using `docker cp` for example:
If you want copy `schema.xml`  from **apacheNutch** container to **solr** container then:

1. `docker cp apacheNutch:/root/nutch/conf/schema.xml /tmp/schema.xml` 
   server/solr/configsets/nutch/
2. `docker cp /tmp/schema.xml
           solr:/opt/solr-8.1.1/server/solr/configsets/nutch/conf`