# Upload file to dockerized app on the fly, then serve

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, file-upload, static

I've got a Python web app that runs inside two Docker containers, one for the FastAPI backend, the other for the Vue.JS front-end (and there's besides a third one, with the Postgres Db). Now my task is to upload a file from inside the front-end client to the server, store it permanently and serve, so that I can use static URLs in my img tags.

A possible similar question is here: [How to upload file outside Docker container in Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530593/how-to-upload-file-outside-docker-container-in-flask-app) But it concerns an approach where the server must be restarted upon upload to reflect the changes. I need to do everything on the fly, as the app is running.

Dockerfile for front-end:

```
FROM node:16.14.2 as builder

WORKDIR /admin

COPY package*.json ./
COPY vite.config.js ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /admin/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Dockerfile for backend:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.9

EXPOSE 8000

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

I can certainly transfer a file (as raw bytes stream) from the front-end to the backend via Axios and receive it on the backend Python side. I can then process it however I like. But how can I store it in the location where the front-end container could read it and serve statically?

### UPDATE (Use Docker Volumes)

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052949/docker-copy-file-from-one-container-to-another), I've tried to use a shared volume for my purpose. My COMPOSE file now looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:

  use_frontend:
    container_name: 'use_frontend'
    # --> ADDED <--
    volumes:
      - 'myshare:/etc/nginx'
      - 'myshare:/usr/share/nginx/html'
    build: 
      context: ./admin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - use_backend
    ports:
      - 8090:80

  use_db:
    container_name: use_db
    image: postgres:14.2
    # etc etc...

  use_backend:
    container_name: 'use_backend'
    volumes:
      # --> ADDED <--
      - 'myshare:/usr/share/nginx/html'
    build: 
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - use_db
    # etc etc...

# --> ADDED <--
volumes:
  myshare:
    driver: local
```

The `Dockerfile` for `use_frontend` hasn't changed (must it?)

```mk
FROM node:16.14.2 as builder

WORKDIR /admin

# copy out files for npm
COPY package*.json ./
COPY vite.config.js ./

# install and build Vue.js
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Nginx image
FROM nginx:1.21

# copy Nginx conf file to VOLUME mounted folder
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# clean everything in VOLUME mounted folder (app entry point)
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
# copy compiled app to to VOLUME mounted folder (app entry point)
COPY --from=builder /admin/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# expose port 80 for HTTP access
EXPOSE 80

# run Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The Nginx conf file hasn't changed either:

```python
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        # app entry point
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # MIME types
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        # etc etc...
    }
}
```

But after doing

```sh
docker compose build
docker compose up
```

I'm getting `file not found` errors from Nginx:

```
use_frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
use_frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
use_frontend  | 2022/07/24 23:21:32 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
use_frontend  | nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What exactly am I doing wrong with the Docker volume mounting?

Comment: Does this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052949/docker-copy-file-from-one-container-to-another

Comment: @viggnah Well, this is quite similar to what I need, thanks! I've updated my post above to reflect the new problem with Docker volumes.